# How to use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter under AndroidX?

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui, androidx

How to use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter under AndroidX?

```
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Game, GameViewHolder> mAdapter;
```

gives an error:

> Type parameter 'com.name.name.viewholder.GameViewHolder' is not within
>   its bound; should extend
>   'android.support.v7.widget.recyclerview.viewholder'

xml:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/games_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_favorite" />
```

Comment: i think the latest firebase ui lib will be having this recyclerview lib as dependency

Comment: i got to this page "https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/4.2.1/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Config.kt" and it says that lib is 27.1.1 (line 28). So you can build the lib yourself after cloning it as module or you can use support lib from 27.1.1 for now.

Answer (score 1):

[There's an issue open on the FirebaseUI Github about this](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1388).

FirebaseUI still uses the support libraries, not androidx. According to that issue, you should be fine by simply adding

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in your `gradle.properties`. Android Studio may complain about incompatible types, but the app will compile.